# file.Move without renaming it

Tags: c#, id3-tag, file-move

Im coding a programm, which should read out the id3 tags of mp3 files, create a Directory named like the artist and then i want to move the mp3 files into the specific artist directory.

When im trying to Move the Mp3 file, it doesnt move it into the subfolder(named like the Artist) of my Musik Directory, which i created.
I just want to Move the Mp3 files, not rename them.

here is my code:

```
   public void moveFiles(string path, string[] title, string[] artist,string [] songs)
    {//loop through the title array
        for(int i=0;i<title.Length;i++)
        {// no artist no name
            if (artist[i] == null)
            { 
                i += 1;
            }//check if sourceFile is existing
            if (File.Exists(songs[i]))
            {//check if destinationFile is existing
                if (File.Exists((@"C:\Musik\" + artist[i] + songs[i])))
                {//if delete
                    File.Delete((@"C:\Musik\" + artist[i] + songs[i]));
                } 
                else
                { //move file from songs[i](sourcePath)to (destinationPath)
                    File.Move(songs[i],(@"C:\Musik\" + artist[i] + songs[i]));                  
                    MessageBox.Show("Das Lied " + title[i] + " wurde erfolgreich verschoben");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(songs[i]+" does not exist!");
            }
        }
    }
```

It only moves my files into the C:\Musik Directory and it's renaming my files like Artist-Song;
Any help is welcome.
Thanks:)

Comment: Tip: You don't need `File.Exists`. `If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown.` And one more: Use `i++` instead of `i += 1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have missed a backslash in your path.  I would strongly suggest using `Path.Combine` for this type of thing too.  It makes it far more readable and is a cleaner way than pure string concatenation.  Also `Path.GetFileName()` is super useful... know it / love it ;)

```
File.Move(songs[i], Path.Combine(@"C:\Musik", Path.Combine(artist[i], Path.GetFileName(songs[i]));
```

**UPDATE**

If you are targeting .Net 4.0 or higher you can use the 4 string override to make this cleaner (as is pointed out in the suggestions).  If you are targeting 3.5 or lower, use the top solution.

```
File.Move(songs[i], Path.Combine(@"C:", "Musik", artist[i], Path.GetFileName(songs[i]));
```

Comment: Except for the `@"C:\Musik\" + artist[i]`, which should be `@"C:\Musik\", artist[i]` instead to *fully* use `Path.Combine`

Comment: I edited this for either targeting 3.5 or lower, OR 4.0 or higher.

Comment: +1 by targeting more than one version of .NET Framework.

Comment: If you are using 3.5 or lower, *chain* the calls so that you are always using `Path.Combine` and not using +.

Comment: @crashmstr Cleaned it up to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed one backslash ("\") in your code.

```
// By popular suggestion, using Path.Combine...
const string dstRootDirectoryName = @"C:\Musik";
var destinationFileName = Path.Combine(dstRootDirectoryName, artist[i], songs[i]);
if (File.Exists(destinationFileName)
{
    File.Delete(destinationFileName);
}
else
{
    File.Move(songs[i], destinationFileName);
    MessageBox.Show("The file:" + title[i] + " was moved");
}
```

Comment: Path.Combine would be better. And `songs[i]` probably contains a complete path, not just a filename.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus We assume its a full path because its "working" as the first parameter of `File.Move`

Comment: @crashmstr agree. Updated answer, using `Path.Combine()` method. Thank you by your suggestion.

Comment: @EvanL there is a 4-string parameter override. [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782933(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: [Takes up to 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.100).aspx) or `params string[] paths` in .Net 4 and up.

Comment: @crashmstr in .Net 4 and higher, I was using 3.5... OP didn't specify.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.Move(songs[i],(@"C:\Musik\" + artist[i] + songs[i]));
```

Add a slash between the folders:

```
File.Move(songs[i],String.Format("C:\Musik\{0}/{1}", artist[i], songs[i]));
```

Also, consider using String.Format instead of the usual string concatenation, it looks more readeable IMO.

Comment: Or let .Net do the work for you and use `Path.Combine`?